# OutOfBoundsException for TicTacToe Game; Issue: arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, arraylist

I am the beginnings of writing a tic-tac-toe game. I just ran it and got the following stack trace:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)
 at TicTacToe.isMarked(TicTacToe.java:23)
 at TicTacToe.mark(TicTacToe.java:59)
 at TicTacToe.main(TicTacToe.java:7)
```

I suspect it is a problem with the way I have the ArrayList setup? I read somewhere about nulls causing problems, but this is my first time dealing with arrays, so I'm not to familiar with the subject. Anyhow, here is my code:

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class TicTacToe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    newBoard();
    ******************System.out.println(mark(1));************
    System.out.println(mark(5));
    System.out.println(mark(9));
   }

 // Creates a blank board.
 public static ArrayList<String> newBoard() {
  ArrayList<String> board = new ArrayList<String>(8);
  return board;
 }

 // Returns true if the square has been marked.
 public static boolean isMarked(int numberOfSquare) {
  if (numberOfSquare > 9 || numberOfSquare < 1) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input a valid square number.");
  }
  ************if (newBoard().get(numberOfSquare - 1) == null) {***********
   return false;
  } else
   return true;
 }

 // Returns the number of moves that have been made.
 public static int moveCount() {
  return countMove();
 }

 // If called, adds 1 to number of moves.
 public static int countMove() {
  int moveNumber = 0;
  moveNumber++;
  return moveNumber;
 }

 // Checks for a win at the specified array location and player (X or O).
 public static boolean checkForWin(int x, int y, int z, int player) {
  if (player == 0) {
   return (newBoard().get(x)).equals("O")
     && (newBoard().get(y)).equals("O")
     && (newBoard().get(y)).equals("O");
  } else {
   return (newBoard().get(x)).equals("O")
     && (newBoard().get(y)).equals("O")
     && (newBoard().get(y)).equals("O");
  }
 }

 // Places an X or O on the specified square.
 public static boolean mark(int markSquareNumber) {
  if (markSquareNumber > 9 || markSquareNumber < 1) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input a valid square number.");
  }
  ***********if (isMarked(markSquareNumber)) {*******************
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Square is already marked.");
  }
  if (moveCount() % 2 != 0) {
   newBoard().add(markSquareNumber - 1, "X");
   countMove();
  } else {
   newBoard().add(markSquareNumber - 1, "O");
   countMove();
  }
  if (checkForWin(0, 1, 2, 1) || checkForWin(3, 4, 5, 1)
    || checkForWin(6, 7, 8, 1)) {
   System.out.println("Player-X just won horizontally!");
   return true;
  } else if (checkForWin(0, 3, 6, 1) || checkForWin(1, 4, 7, 1)
    || checkForWin(2, 5, 8, 1)) {
   System.out.println("Player-X just won vertically!");
   return true;
  } else if (checkForWin(0, 4, 5, 1) || checkForWin(2, 4, 6, 1)
    || checkForWin(0, 4, 8, 1)) {
   System.out.println("Player-X just won diagonally!");
   return true;
  }
  if (checkForWin(0, 1, 2, 0) || checkForWin(3, 4, 5, 0)
    || checkForWin(6, 7, 8, 0)) {
   System.out.println("Player-O just won horizontally!");
   return true;
  } else if (checkForWin(0, 3, 6, 0) || checkForWin(1, 4, 7, 0)
    || checkForWin(2, 5, 8, 0)) {
   System.out.println("Player-O just won vertically!");
   return true;
  } else if (checkForWin(0, 4, 5, 0) || checkForWin(2, 4, 6, 0)
    || checkForWin(0, 4, 8, 0)) {
   System.out.println("Player-O just won diagonally!");
   return true;
  } else
   return false;
 }
}
```

I just put a whole bunch of asterisks by the lines that came up in the stack-trace. If anyone could point out where I am going wrong that would be splendid, thanks!

**Ok, here is the solution that I came up with after all your wonderful input: (Please only use this for educational and reference purposes, I don't want to get yelled at by my professor if you are in my CS1410 class and you copy me!!!!)**

```
//Written by JTN for Assignment7.3- CS1410; October 2010. 
import java.util.*;

public class TicTacToe {
private static int moveNumber = 0;
private static ArrayList<String> board = new ArrayList<String>(8);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        newBoard();
        mark(1);mark(2);
        mark(5);mark(3);
        mark(9);
        boardString();
    }
    // Returns the number of moves that have been made.
    public static int moveCount() {
        return (countMove()-1);
    }

    // If called, adds 1 to number of moves.
    public static int countMove() {
        moveNumber= moveNumber + 1;
        return moveNumber;
    }
    // Creates a blank board.
    public static ArrayList<String> newBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
            board.add("_");
        return board;
    }

    // Returns true if the square has been marked.
    public static boolean isMarked(int numberOfSquare) {
        if (numberOfSquare > 9 || numberOfSquare < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input a valid square number.");
        }
        if ((board.get(numberOfSquare - 1)).equals("_")) {
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }



    // Checks for a win at the specified array location and player (X or O).
    public static boolean checkForWin(int x, int y, int z, int player) {
        if (player == 0) {
            return     (board.get(x)).equals("O")
                    && (board.get(y)).equals("O")
                    && (board.get(z)).equals("O");
        } 
        else {
            return     (board.get(x)).equals("X")
                    && (board.get(y)).equals("X")
                    && (board.get(z)).equals("X");
        }
    }

    // Places an X or O on the specified square.
    public static boolean mark(int markSquareNumber) {
        if (markSquareNumber > 9 || markSquareNumber < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input a valid square number.");
        }
        if (isMarked(markSquareNumber)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Square is already marked.");
        }       
        if ((countMove() % 2) == 0){
            board.set(markSquareNumber - 1, "O");
        }
        else {
            board.set(markSquareNumber - 1, "X");
        } 

        if (checkForWin(0, 1, 2, 1) || checkForWin(3, 4, 5, 1)
                || checkForWin(6, 7, 8, 1)) {
            System.out.println("Player-X just won horizontally!");
            return true;
        } else if (checkForWin(0, 3, 6, 1) || checkForWin(1, 4, 7, 1)
                || checkForWin(2, 5, 8, 1)) {
            System.out.println("Player-X just won vertically!");
            return true;
        } else if (checkForWin(0, 4, 5, 1) || checkForWin(2, 4, 6, 1)
                || checkForWin(0, 4, 8, 1)) {
            System.out.println("Player-X just won diagonally!");
            return true;
        }
         else if (checkForWin(0, 1, 2, 0) || checkForWin(3, 4, 5, 0)
                || checkForWin(6, 7, 8, 0)) {
            System.out.println("Player-O just won horizontally!");
            return true;
        } else if (checkForWin(0, 3, 6, 0) || checkForWin(1, 4, 7, 0)
                || checkForWin(2, 5, 8, 0)) {
            System.out.println("Player-O just won vertically!");
            return true;
        } else if (checkForWin(0, 4, 5, 0) || checkForWin(2, 4, 6, 0)
                || checkForWin(0, 4, 8, 0)) {
            System.out.println("Player-O just won diagonally!");
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }

    public static String boardString(){
        String row1 = board.get(0)+"|"+board.get(1)+"|"+board.get(2);
        String row2 = board.get(3)+"|"+board.get(4)+"|"+board.get(5);
        String row3 = board.get(6)+"|"+board.get(7)+"|"+board.get(8);
        System.out.println(row1);
        System.out.println(row2);
        System.out.println(row3);
        return row1+row2+row3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please format you code? Select the code and then press the 100100 button on the top of the editor.

Comment: Please edit your post and fix the code formatting.  This will generate a lot more feedback/answers for you.  [EDIT] Looks like shoebox639 beat me to it.

Comment: Sorry, I had it formatted, but then something happened? It is fixed now.

Comment: Just commenting on design: you don't want to put check for victory in the mark() method. And your checkForWin method really should have no arguments and just return the winner, -1 if no one won. In the check victories you can do your hardcoded check.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of the victory check thing...as to the question, I am just doing what my professor told us to do. Well, he only asked to return true or false, but that just helps me verify its working when it prints how who and where they won. I actually found some more errors, but I will update and victory as soon as I am done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line

```
ArrayList<String> board = new ArrayList<String>(8);
```

will **not create an array of 8 strings** (or 9 strings for that matter, if that was the intention). It will create an ArrayList with initial *capacity* of 8 elements, but of size 0.

After you've created the ArrayList for the board, you'll have to populate it with elements using the `add`-method. Try doing something like:

```
public static ArrayList<String> newBoard() {
    ArrayList<String> board = new ArrayList<String>(8);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        board.add("");
    return board;
}
```

The message `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` says that you're trying to access the 0th element in a list of length 0 (in a list without elements).

Furthermore, the following line:

```
newBoard().add(markSquareNumber - 1, "X");
```

should probably be

```
newBoard().set(markSquareNumber - 1, "X");
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to have fixed that problem! :) For the record and for this particular situation, it needs to be i <= 8 or you will still get the same error because 0-8 exclusive is only 8 and there are nine boxes in tic-tac-toe, but just a minor tweak. Thanks again for solving my stupidity!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is no initial population of the list. You're trying to access elements that don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

From the wall of unformatted code, I think I know your problem.

```
public static ArrayList newBoard() { 
    ArrayList board = new ArrayList(8); 
    return board; 
}
```

Doesn't initialize anything in the arraylist. It is currently empty with 0 objects. This is what you want.

```
public static ArrayList newBoard() { 
    ArrayList<String> board = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        board.add("");
    }
    return board; 
}
```

I question why you don't just use a `String[]`, in which case `new String[9]` will create 9 actual Strings.

And by the way, a tic tac toe board has 9 squares, I don't know what you only created it with 8.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is a dinamic structure. Even if you put a "size" when you create it, it will not fill the arraylist. If you want you can fill it by yourself or use a simple Array.

Other thing, your countMove() function is always returning 1. Because you are setting 0 and appling the ++ OP to 0 as well. If you want that behavior just return 1

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I just realized this too...any idea how to get it to increase each time a move is made? I go off the fact that if x always goes first, then they will always be on an odd move 1,3,5,etc...so having it incremented each time a person marks something is imperative.

Comment: you can have a global variable and countMove() just for increment. But if you want to have a count per user you can have an Array and each entry of that array is the count for that user.

Comment: a better and elegant solution is to have a class "Player" and one variable "moves". Each instance will modify its local variable and is more "clean".

Comment: Thanks! I think I have it all running how I want to now!

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed array size like you have here, I'm not sure why you're using an `ArrayList`, and not just a simple `String[]` array?  If you initialize your array with:

```
String[] board = new String[9];
```

You will then actually be able to get the value of any square without having to worry about being out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your `newBoard()` function every time you try to get an element from your `ArrayList<String>`.  This will return an empty `ArrayList<String>` every time.

You need to initialize the list and then call the get function on that variable.  The other answers explain this.

Answer (score 0):

```
newBoard().get(numberOfSquare - 1) == null)
```

Every time you call the `newBoard()` method, you create a new `ArrayList` object with no element.
If you try to get something on an empty `ArrayList`, you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the stated problem, you seem to be calling a `newBoard()` method each time, creating a new `ArrayList`, which wouldn't actually have anything as people have stated above. It doesn't make sense to do that. You probably want to have a single board object to check whether a player has won.